# How to vectorize two for loops in matlab for speed up

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

How can I speed up the two `for` loops below by vectorization in MATLAB? This is a part of an iterative algorithm and I need to do it many times.

```
Temp1=0;
Temp2=0;

for i=1:m_plus
    for j=1:m_minus
        Temp1=Temp1+(p_m(j,:)-p_p(i,:))';
        Temp2=Temp2+(p_m(j,:)-p_p(i,:))'*(p_m(j,:)-p_p(i,:));
    end
end
```

Comment: what are the values of m_plus and m_minus? What are the dimensions of p_m and p_p? How large they can be?

Comment: m_plus and m_minus are scalar values. p_m and p_p are non-square matrices which have different rows and same columns. The can be for example:p_m: 1000 * 200  and p_p: 1500 * 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

```
m_plus = size(p_p,1);
m_minus = size(p_m,1);
```

then it's easy enough to do `Temp1` without loops

```
Temp1 = (m_plus*sum(p_m)-m_minus*sum(p_p))'
```

For `Temp2` it's easy to get rid of one of the loops,

```
Temp2 = 0;
for idx = 1:m_plus
    temp = p_m-ones(m_minus,1)*p_p(idx,:); % or could use bsxfun to do this
    Temp2 = Temp2 + temp'*temp;
end
```

although with a little more thought it may be possible to get rid of this loop too.

Comment: Dear Goddard, Thank for your answer and time. I checked results for Temp1 and Temp2 for both cases (with vectorization and without), results for Temp2 is slightly different. Please kindly let me know is it still correct?

Comment: This small difference has no effect on final result in my code. I do appreciate you. I will try for removing second loop. Thank again Goddard.

Comment: The difference should be in the 1e-15 (or less) range.  That is due to the different order in which math operations are performed.  Both are correct, for the order in which they are calculated.

Comment: +1 for this smart approach and additionally on getting my attention to this interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

Another vectorized approach that is sort of inspired from [Phil's smart answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24073949/3293881) -

```
t1 = bsxfun(@minus,p_m,permute(p_p,[3 2 1]));
t2 = reshape(permute(t1,[1 3 2]),m_minus*m_plus,[]);
Temp1 = sum(t2)'; %//'
Temp2 = t2'*t2;
```

Comment: Thank you Divakar, However, As I tested both codes on matlab. The line Temp2 = t2'*t2; consumes time a lot, so that the code is slower than using only one for loop. I do not understand why this line is time consuming.

Comment: @Pey The calculation of `Temp1` of this `bsxfun` implementation definitely looks slower than @Phil's solution on that, but then `Temp2` calculation of this solution needs the values from the `bsxfun`. Overall, for calculation of both `Temp1` and `Temp2` becomes comparable with @Phil's solution, but I am not sure if my solution is showing any appreciable performance improvement over the other solution.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, your effort is worthwhile, because you did not use any for loop. I learnt many things of you and Phil solution regarding vectorization.

Comment: @Pey That sounds great really!